# Cannot access JavaScript var from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having problems echoing a PHP variable that i am getting from a form from JavaScript. In JavaScript the variables can be logged without problems, but when trying to echo from PHP, I get "err".
I am using JQuery with this.

JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#soegform").submit (function (event){
        var formData = {
            soegtitel: $("#soegtitel").val(),
            soegforfatter: $("#soegforfatter").val()
        }
        console.log(formData)

        
        if($.trim(formData) != '') {
            $.post('name.php', {formData: formData}, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#visliste').text(data);
            });
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I get the correct output from the console.log(formData), so accessing the HTML form shouldn't be the problem.

PHP file:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$titel = (!empty($data->soegtitel)) ?$data->soegtitel:"err";
$forfatter = (!empty($data->soegforfatter)) ?$data->soegforfatter:"err";
echo $titel;
```

My output from echo $titel; is err, so something went wrong. Please help, as I have been trying to solve this to no avail, for several hours.
Thanks

Comment: What is `if($.trim(formData) != '')` supposed to do/check? `formData` is an object. `$.trim()` removes white-space from a string. o.O

Comment: Check the request in the browser and the server. It won't be what you think it is (`data: { formData: formData }` should be `data: formData`)

Comment: Did you check if the data is getting posted to the file?, to do so, in nam.php `echo $_POST['formData'];` I prefer this for debugging.